# What is wrong with this c# method that uses Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I tried writing a method that, given an int Enumerable and an int variable (let's call it n), it generates all the Subsequences whose sum is smaller than n.

Here's how it goes:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> SubSWithSumSmallerThanN(this IEnumerable<int> intEnum, int n)
    {
        var numbers = intEnum.ToList();
        return Enumerable
            .Range(1, numbers.Count)
            .SelectMany(length => Enumerable.Range(0, numbers.Count - length + 1)
                                            .Select(x => numbers.TakeWhile(y => numbers.IndexOf(y) > x && numbers.IndexOf(y) < x + length)))
                                            .Where(x => x.Sum() <= n)
            .ToArray();
    }
```

Basically, this doesn't work. For a simple example, like

```
{1, 5, 3, 8}, n = 7
```

while the result should be

```
{{1}, {5}, {3}, {1, 5}}
```

the actual result is this:

```
Expected: List<IEnumerable<Int32>> [[1], [5], [3], [1, 5]]
Actual:   IEnumerable`1[] []
```

It generates a mostly empty IEnumerable. How should i fix it?

Comment: Have you debugged it? I dread to think what the complexity of your algorithm is, with all of those `IndexOf`s (plus that will stop it working when you have duplicate numbers)

Comment: why {1,3} not exist in the expected result?

Comment: because it's not a sequence. to get {1, 3} you'd have to skip 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a solution using `for` loops quite easily:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> SubsequencesLessThen(IReadOnlyList<int> input, int limit)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j = i; j < input.Count; j++)
        {
            sum += input[j];
            if (sum >= limit)
                break;

            yield return input.Skip(i).Take(j - i + 1);
        }
    }
}
```

The closest equivalent I could come up with using only linq is:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> SubsequencesLessThen2(IReadOnlyList<int> input, int limit)
{
    return from i in Enumerable.Range(0, input.Count)
        from j in Enumerable.Range(i, input.Count - i)
        let elements = input.Skip(i).Take(j - i + 1)
        let sum = elements.Sum()
        where sum <= limit
        select elements;
}
```

This is quite a bit more expensive: we don't stop as soon as we notice the sum going above the limit, so this will calculate `1+5` then `1+5+3` then `1+5+3+8` then `5+3`, and so on. We also re-calculate the sum each time, rather than keeping a running total.